# What does 32bit/8bit and two complement mean when talking about integers?

Tags: java, graphics, integer

A book i'm working on keeps on mentioning storing colour values in 24bit or 8 bit integers. I searched through the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) but all it mentions is that integer/byte are "32-bit signed two's complement integer/8bit signed".Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The books is talking about how the color information is stored, and how many values it can have.

Integers can be stored in many different sized containers, but the most common in C/C++ (and probably Java?) are:

- 8 bit (i.e. `char`)
- 16 bit (i.e. `short`)
- 32 bit (i.e. `int` or `long`)

In your case, 24bit is referring to the fact that it's using 24 bits to store the color information, which gives you 2^24 color values (16,777,216). Similarly an 8 bit color value can store 256 values.

2's comp refers to the method of representing signed values. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Color values are generally unsigned, as far as I know, so it doesn't really apply to your question.

Comment: Where did you get the 2 from in the 2^24?

Comment: It's the base. So since the values are all stored as binary "bits", which are either a 0 or 1, and you have 24 of them, you get 2^24 different values.

Comment: @IntentFilters if I have 2 bits of information (i.e. 2 1s or 0s) I can store 00 01 10 11 (4 values, or 2^2), if I have 3 bits of information I can store 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111 (8 values or 2^3) etc etc etc all the way up to 24 bits is 2^24 values